# Three.js update size of shape

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to figure out how to update the size of a custom shape in Three.js. 
I have a L shaped plane where I want to update just one of the sides so it looks more like a L and not like a bracket.

```
+++++                                         +++++
+++++                                         +++++
+++++                                         +++++
+++++                                         +++++
+++++++++++++                                 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++                                 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++ I want this to go to this >     ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

The only way I can figure out how to change the size at all is by using object.scale which wont change the shape. Only over all size.

Here is my jsfiddle try: http://jsfiddle.net/phacer/JGPxv/

Comment: You need update vertices. Find updateShape function in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JGPxv/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding a second rectangle that I scale the way I want.